# What's the easiest way to display large queries using the Django frame work?

Tags: python, html, django, orm

I am working on an internal database that a handful of people will be using to access.  In short there will be a non-authenticated search page that will allow them to do partial searched on various fields.

I am trying to figure out the best way to display upwards of 1000 individual components.  Ideally it would show a list of N components on a page.  But since I do not know the size of the query until they press search I don't know how to split it up.

I am fearful this is a case of I don't what I don't know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want [Django's pagination](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/pagination/).  That should allow you to query a database, and split the resulting objects across pages.  It even has [an example](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/pagination/#using-paginator-in-a-view).

Comment: I must say `pagination` would not have been on my list of things to search for :).  But this appears to be exactly what I was looking for.